# Is this :$(a+\frac{1}{n})^{n!}+(b+\frac{1}{n})^{n!}$ integer number for some positives integer $n, a, b$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have tried to use reccurence demonstartion to show that :$(a+\frac{1}{n})^{n!}+(b+\frac{1}{n})^{n!}$ is integer number for $a, b$ are positive integers  but i failed because i got a complicated formula .the last let me
feel that is integer for some values of $n $, then **My question here is** :

How do I show that : $$(a+\frac{1}{n})^{n!}+(b+\frac{1}{n})^{n!}$$ is integer for finitely many positive integer $n$ for a postive integer $a$ and $b $ ?

**Note:** For some examples which i got in Wolfram alpha show that is very approximated to integers for $n=3$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B1%2F3)%5E3!%2B(2%2B1%2F3)%5E3!) with many values of $a$ and $b$ , and the motivation of this question is to know more about formula which produce integers and in the same time formula which produces primes !!!

Thank you for any help

Comment: Will this ever be an integer if $n>2$? Do you have any examples?

Comment: good , my question is not for n >2 , is for many finitely positive integer n , i have tried n=3 for some values a, b i got numbers approixmated to integer , now i would like to know when does that could be integer  ?

Comment: Again, do you any example of $a, b, n$ for which the given sum is an integer?

Comment: Can you quantify your question? What is fixed and what exactly do you want? (At east a few, at most finitely many, or what?)

Comment: Is the above formula integer number for some positive values of a, b, n , I meant if can be integer for finitely many positive integer n ?

Comment: The  only example which let me conjuctred that is for n>2 is n=3 for some values of a and b

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan, try n=3 and a=8 , b=5 we get a number very approixmated to integer

Comment: So this is what MO has evolved to ...

Comment: @HeinrichD If you think this is a poor question, downvote it! Despite the grammar issues in the post there is a legitimately interesting question here - albeit one that might be worth migrating to math.SE rather than leaving here.

Comment: I'm confused if it is work with n=2 , someone give me a proof about that which affirmed that is work only with n=2 and i'm not asserted that is work for all positive integer n , the best example which show we get a very approximated number to integer for n>2 is n=3 and a=b+1

Comment: This can never be an integer for $n>2$ for elementary reasons. The question is indeed somehow legitimate but has nothing to do on MO, I think it should be moved to math.SE.

(To prove it multiply by $n^{n!}$ and compute modulo $n$. If it were an integer it should give $0$, but the result is always $2$ modulo $n$, hence it cannot be an integer for $n>2$.)

Comment: For $n=2$ it is always half-integer, not an integer.

Comment: @ nice Fedor and this what i got for n=2 always is half integer , if it is integer i think for n=3 and a=b+1  not large

Comment: For $n>2$ see the comment by Simon Henry.

Comment: Thanks , i saw that , then the above formula can  not be integer for every positive integer n